# Should we ban the "learning-craft" tag?

Tags: discussion

For pretty much its entire existence, the [learning-craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-craft) tag has been horribly misused...

> https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-craft

Of course, **we're all** "learning Craft"... that's why we're asking questions about it!

It seems to be the easy go-to for newbies who just don't know where to start. They're not sure exactly what to tag their question, so [learning-craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-craft) seems like a reasonable place to start.

Personally, I've only every felt the tag was appropriate when people are asking about **learning resources** specifically. In other words, questions that might be answered with links to Mijingo, or other webcasts and tutorials of that nature.

**Should we eliminate the [learning-craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-craft) tag?**

Comment: The only case I have _for_ the tag are the (few) questions that attempt to size up Craft and see whether it'd be an appropriate fit for project requirements. I don't think this is [tag:learning-craft], but how would you describe that? [tag:project-research] or [tag:requirements]?

Comment: I would up assigning [tag:craft-features] for broad "is Craft a good fit for X" or "can Craft Y" questions, and freshly-minted [tag:resources] for places to find help whether it's from contractors or learning materials. I added descriptions to both to try and clarify my intent.

Comment: Does an `evaluating-craft` tag make sense?

Comment: @Sandwich Possibly. That strikes me as a separate question though, feel free to start a new thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we should. After going through all the questions with that tag, I'm convinced it's redundant and in some cases a poor substitute for choosing more specific+relevant alternatives.

I'll even volunteer myself to re-tag current [learning-craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-craft) posts to model better conventions for introductory questions. But only if you accept my answer.

Comment: Answer accepted! Thanks man, feel free to work your magic. :)

Comment: Magic accomplished, @LindseyD.

Comment: Mischief managed! Thanks @MattStein! https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/31/f2/6331f2b31f190839688dff86a873a202.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It's always felt like an odd tag to me, too. Would not be against killing it.